# MySQL - How to select data based on another select (subselect?)

Tags: mysql

It is only my second Query and I wonder, is there any chance to get what I need.

I'am working with Prestashop and I would like to export data about the product.

With the select "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ac.id_product_2)" I'am getting the product (which I need) ID, but I would like to get the product reference based on these ID.

I wonder, is there any change to get the product reference based on those ID?

My query is:

```
SELECT p.id_product, pl.name, p.reference, p.mcompleted,pl.description_short, pl.meta_title, 
pl.link_rewrite, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ac.id_product_2) 
FROM ps_product p 
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available s ON (p.id_product = s.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_accessory ac ON (ac.id_product_1 = p.id_product)
WHERE pl.id_lang = 2 
AND p.active = 1
AND s.quantity > 0
AND p.id_product > 35000
AND p.mcompleted = 1
GROUP BY p.id_product
```

Right know I'am getting the data something like this:

```
id_product     reference     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ac.id_product_2)  
 35026           21-176F      35026,35027
 35027           55-FFFF      35027,35028
 35028           66-FFFF      35026,35028

But I would like to get something like  this:
id_product     reference     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ac.id_product_2)  
 35026           21-176F      21-176F,55-FFFF 
 35027           55-FFFF      55-FFFF,66-FFFF 
 35028           66-FFFF      21-176F,66-FFFF
```

Already spent 6+ hours on internet, hoping for Your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ac.id_product_2 also links to the ps_product table then you could simple make another join and concatenate the reference instead of the id.

```
SELECT p.id_product, pl.name, p.reference, p.mcompleted,pl.description_short, pl.meta_title, 
pl.link_rewrite, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p2.reference) 
FROM ps_product p 
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available s ON (p.id_product = s.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_accessory ac ON (ac.id_product_1 = p.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_product p2 on (p2.id_product = ac.id_product_2)
WHERE pl.id_lang = 2 
AND p.active = 1
AND s.quantity > 0
AND p.id_product > 35000
AND p.mcompleted = 1
GROUP BY p.id_product
```

Comment: It worked! For more than 2 weeks I have wondered how should I get the data I need... Just save another two weeks of wondering. Thank you very much!